# did firebase console drop support for opening a specific firestore document via URL?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Previously it was possible to open URLs in the firebase console like this:

[https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/lyour-project-id/firestore/data~2Fusers~2FuserID](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/lyour-project-id/firestore/data%7E2Fusers%7E2FuserID)

this would open the firestore collection `users` and the user with id `userID`. Since a few days I noticed that this behavior is no longer supported. Is there a way around that?

In backend admin panels this is a very nice feature, I usually link all documents directly like that for fast access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I don't think this was intentionally changed, or at least I'm not aware of such a change.

If you can reproduce this consistently, please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the support team so that they can investigate.

Comment: thanks, I just filed a bug report, since the issue still persists and is also reproducable on different machines / browsers / accounts. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also came here to the same situation, It's happening 100% of times.
Simply open a Firestore document in the console and refresh the page. 
It will not open that document and instead it will open the first document of the first collection.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @InfoStatus. Please report to the support link above, as it's the simplest way to get it in front of the responsible engineer(s).

Comment: It's now fixed. Thank you